# Несколько окон с кодом VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность в vs2019 сделать 2 окна с кодом по дефолту?

если я закрываю все окна в правой(левой) части с кодом vs, то оставшееся окно с кодом автоматически растягивается на всю ширину VS.

хочу сделать, что-бы при закрытии вкладок с кодом в одной части экрана, оставалось пустое окно без вкладок, куда потом можно будет перетащить вкладки.

Comment: Есть подозрение, как можно подойти к самостоятельному решению этой задачи. Есть такой плагинчик - VCmd. Он позволяет вешать хуки на действия с интерфейсом VS, и даёт программный доступ к интерфейсу. Грубо говоря, "если пользователь переключился на вкладку с дизайном формы - открой ему properties, а если на вкладку с кодом-закрой" - такие штуки можно там делать. Возможно, в таких терминах получилось бы сделать и то, что Вы хотите